# JavaFX DirectoryChooser probable bug on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, javafx

I'm developing an application using JavaFX and I have to use a DirectoryChooser. I'm calling it through the following code:

```
 DirectoryChooser chooser = new DirectoryChooser();
 chooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("~/Downloads/"));
 chooser.initialDirectoryProperty();
 chooser.setTitle("JavaFX Projects");

 Button browse = new Button("Browse");
 browse.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                     File  file=chooser.showDialog(MyStage);

                    if (file != null) {

                     downloadPath.setText(file.getPath());

                    }

                }
            });
```

On Mac OS X DirectoryChooser opens, but it doesn't set customized title and the app isn't blocked by it, I can still use it and open other DirectoryChooser dialogs.

On Windows systems the same code works perfectly, both title setting and app blocking.

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Try using a [java 8 preview release](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html) and see if your issue is fixed.

Comment: On release JDK 8 (1.8.0_60-b27) the title is still not shown. Grrrrrr